# Ensure Observable Array is populated before Filter runs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2, knockout-3.0

**Problem**: When My filter method is executing that is used to display an Html element, my observable array has not been populated yet by my web-api call resulting in nothing to filter from.

**My Solution** : 
If I place an alert right before my filter method execution, everything seems to be working. 
Length of my observable array is 0 right before my alert call whereas it has a value after my alert.

**Question**: How can I ensure my array is populated without placing an alert. 
This issue is occurring on multiple Pages, placing an alert before my Html is rendered makes everything works fine.

I have a simple Observable Array and a Filter Method on it. 
Part of my Knockout Code :

```
self.currentVendorSupport = ko.observable(new VendorContact());

//Populates Observable Array - allManufactures 
self.allManufacturers = ko.observableArray([]);
 $.getJSON(serviceRoot + '/api/Manufacturer', function (data) {  
    var mappedManufacturers = $.map(data, function (item) {
        return new Manufacturer(manID = item.manID, name = item.name);
    });
    self.allManufacturers(mappedManufacturers);
});

//Filters allManufacturers 
self.GetCurrentVendor = function () {
 alert('allManufacturerLength value again:' + allManufacturerLength);
 return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.allManufacturers(), function (item) {
     return item.manID === self.currentVendorSupport().manID();
        });
}
```

It seems to be working. 
It is not working with arrayFilter though, is it because of return type difference between the two, wrong syntax or something else?

```
self.GetCurrentManufacturer = ko.computed(function () {
if (self.allManufacturers().length > 0) 
{ 
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.allManufacturers(), function (item) 
    { 
    return item.manufacturerID === 
           self.currentVendorSupport().manufacturerID() }); 
    } 
else return new Manufacturer(0, '...'); 
}, self); 

Html Code: 
<label class="control-label readOnlyLabel" data-bind="text: GetCurrentVendor().name"></label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply make `GetCurrentVendor` a [computedObservable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) instead so that you can conditionally show a value based on the observable array length. Since it is computed it would `react` on changes made to the array and update its value.

You can even make it [pureComputed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) so it is only ever activated/computed when called.

For example the computedObservable `currentVendor` would show "***...***" when the array is empty and the filtered name when the array is populated.

**Computed**:

```
self.currentVendor = ko.computed(function () {
    if(this.allManufacturers().length > 0) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.allManufacturers(), function (item) {
            return item.manID === this.currentVendorSupport().manID();
        }).name;
    } else {
        return '...'
    }
}, this)
```

**HTML**:

```
<label class="control-label readOnlyLabel" data-bind="text: currentVendor"></label>
```

Comment: this is the way to go

Comment: It's difficult to admit, but twice now you came in and wrote an answer that made a lot more sense than mine that I couldn't help upvoting it. I'm a fan!

Comment: @user877247 not sure I follow. What is `arrayFilter`? You just have to make sure your computed returns a String so that you can show that on the screen. Make sure you do not return Object/Array since those when `unboxed` would not print what you expect.

Comment: @Akrion : It seems to be working. It is not working with arrayFilter though, is it because of return type difference between the two, wrong syntax or something else? Please see self.GetCurrentManufacturer in my code above. I am just trying to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Well sure this is what I was saying in my prev. comment ... `arrayFilter` returns an array so in your computed in one case you are returning an array on the other an object. You need to be consistent and return the same type.

Comment: @Akrion : I asked a similar question but added it as new. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082031/asp-net-web-forms-and-knockout-maintaining-state

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code is written such that `GetCurrentVendor` is called only once, by the HTML. And obviously it's called too soon and doesn't get updated afterwards. This is *exactly* what an observable is for, so that the HTML gets updated when the JS values get updated. So try this:

**JS**

```
self.currentVendorSupport = ko.observable(new VendorContact());

//Populates Observable Array - allManufactures 
self.allManufacturers = ko.observableArray([]);

//New observable, initially empty
self.currentVendorName = ko.observable();
  $.getJSON(serviceRoot + '/api/Manufacturer', function (data) {  
  var mappedManufacturers = $.map(data, function (item) {
     return new Manufacturer(manID = item.manID, name = item.name);
  });
  self.allManufacturers(mappedManufacturers);
  //updated value after api call is complete
  self.currentVendorName(self.GetCurrentVendor().name);
});

//Filters allManufacturers 
self.GetCurrentVendor = function () {
  //alert('allManufacturerLength value again:' + allManufacturerLength);
  return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.allManufacturers(), function (item) {
     return item.manID === self.currentVendorSupport().manID();
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
//this automatically updates when a new value is available
<label class="control-label readOnlyLabel" data-bind="text: currentVendorName"></label>
```